# When searching in Yandex mail with imap, i get an BACKEND SEARCH ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, imap

I am trying to search emails from yandex using IMAP, but I get the error

```
Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  SEARCH Backend error. sc=jgeTdx5CdCg0_101156_imap-production-84
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/imap.rb:1222:in `get_tagged_response'
```

The search request here:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.yandex.ru', 993, true)
imap.login(my_yandex_email, my_password_for_app)
imap.select("INBOX")
email = Email.first
imap.search(["HEADER", "Message-ID", email.message_id)
```

I dont know what to do. For GMAIL this code is working fine

I want this code to work, or maybe you can offer another solution to get a definite email. I cant use 'ALL' parameter, cause i have about 100 email per minute

Comment: Not all servers support rich text searching functions, since they’re intended to just be used by a client that downloads email and handles it locally.  Use a different server, or cache headers locally.